# how to find public day in shamsi calendar?

Tags: calendar

I'm looking for a way to find a holiday in the Shamsi calendar, I tried many ways. 
But in the end, I came to the conclusion that I had to enter the information manually

Another way I tried was to use moment Library (Persian and Jalali edition - [ساعت ایران](https://8box.ir/%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%AA-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86) )
And this is my code :

```
var moment = require('moment-jalaali')
moment().format('jYYYY/jM/jD')
```

But I couldn't get results that way either

Do you think there is a way other than entering manual information?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use data insertion manually , and other way is using Ready databases

such as Jdf website ( I've used it before ، it's very usefull )